# Vaadin grid horizontal scroll

Tags: scroll, grid, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to avoid horizontal scroll in Vaadin grid and oblige column to be resized according to the screen. I tried `grid.setExpandRatio()` but I have no change.
Have you any idea please?

Comment: Please provide code for reproduction and a screen shot. Is the scroll bar in your grid shown because column values are too long?

Comment: I have many column and column values are too long .I want to fix the grid size and increase and decrease column size according to situation

Comment: It's really easier when you provide your code. Is the Grid 100% width?

Comment: grid is in a layout like this:grid = new Grid();
  grid.setSizeFull();
  grid.setHeight(15, Unit.EM);
  grid.setImmediate(true);
  grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);                                                                           and I use this layout in annother layout which has only height fixed

Answer (score 1):

The Vaadin Grid component provides width control for each column. See [API doc](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html).

You can set expand ratio of each column that is added when additional free space is available beside the space that is required for each column. But this doesn't help in your case. The best way I found so far is to set a maximum width for a column that is suitable for shrinking.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Steffen but I use column.setExpendRatio(1) and nothing is changed

Comment: You are right, I changed my answer. Seems that there is no proper way to do what you would like to have.

Comment: I'd like to know with someone have solved the problem with the grid horizontal scrollbar appearing when it is not really necessary. I have a simple grid with 5 columns and the content of then is not so large but Vaadin is still putting the horizontal scrollbar on the grid component.